# How to add a delay to dropdown menus in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to add an 'animated' look to my dropdown menu so that it doesn't immediately appear while hovering. Not sure how to go about it. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Example: [Demo](https://codepen.io/J_Enrique/pen/RJBOvY)

Here is my code currently: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/chassisgh/pen/wvmGoQp)

```css
nav{
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: white;
}

nav ul {
  float: left;
}

nav ul li{
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a{
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Forum';
  color: black;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li ul{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 5px 10px; /* spacing between hovering overlay and full outline */
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}

nav ul li:hover ul{
  display: block;
}

nav ul li ul li{
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

nav ul li ul li a{
  padding: 8px 0px;
}

nav ul li ul li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(135, 206, 250, 0.5);
  padding: 8px 4px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
```

```html
<html onclick="play()" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Socials ⤵</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/chassis.gh/">Instagram</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://discordapp.com/users/259405254335004685">Discord</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://t.me/chassis_gh">Telegram</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://github.com/chassisGH">GitHub</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

(PS) sorry if this post is low-quality or breaks any rules, it's my first.

Answer (score 0):

Okay first of all you cannot make transition to something that is display none..you have 2 options:
1.visibility.
2.Opacity
I also Used Transform translate to move it up in the first place the moving it back when hover.
and transition of all in 0.5s ease

```css
@import url('css.css');
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Forum);
/*---------------------------------------/*
/* nav bar */
nav{
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: white;
}

/* 'socials' */
nav ul {
  float: left;
}

/* dif socials */
nav ul li{
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;   /* hides until hovering */
}
/* styling for text in navigation */
nav ul li a{
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Forum';
  color: black;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* styling for dropdown */
nav ul li ul{
  z-index:-99;
  visibility:hidden;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 5px 10px; /* spacing between hovering overlay and full outline */
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  transform:translateY(-20%);
  transition:all 0.5s ease;
}

/* hover effect */
nav ul li:hover ul{
  visibility:visible;
  transform:translateY(0%);
}

/* dropdown items */
nav ul li ul li{
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
/* padding for dropdown items */
nav ul li ul li a{
  padding: 8px 0px;
}

/* overlay while hovering over items */
nav ul li ul li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(135, 206, 250, 0.5);
  padding: 8px 4px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html onclick="play()" lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Forum&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Socials ⤵</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/chassis.gh/">Instagram</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://discordapp.com/users/259405254335004685">Discord</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://t.me/chassis_gh">Telegram</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://github.com/chassisGH">GitHub</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not the same effect as in the codepen

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
nav ul li:hover ul {
animation: animate 300ms ease-in-out forwards;
transform-origin: top center;
display: block; }

@keyframes animate {
 0% {
    transform: scale(0)
 }
 80% {
    transform: scale(1.1)
 }
 100% {
    transform: scale(1)
 }
}
```